Python Multiple Inheritance generates "TypeError: got multiple values for keyword argument"
I'm running into a problem using multiple inheritance in Python.  In my code, Child class A inherits from two Parent classes, B and C, both abstract base classes. Each of the Parent classes, B and C, inherit from a common Parent (or Grandparent) class D.  Class D is also an abstract base class.
Instantiating my Child class generates the following error:
TypeError: __main__.D.__init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'd'
This looks to me like it might be related to the classic diamond problem?
    class D
    /     \
class B  class C
    \     /
    class A

But as I understand it, Python's Method Resolution Order is supposed to address this problem.
Displaying the MRO for each class:
print(f"MRO: {[x.__name__ for x in A.__mro__]}")
print(f"MRO: {[x.__name__ for x in B.__mro__]}")
print(f"MRO: {[x.__name__ for x in C.__mro__]}")
print(f"MRO: {[x.__name__ for x in D.__mro__]}")

returns exactly what I would expect to see:
MRO: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'ABC', 'object']
MRO: ['B', 'D', 'ABC', 'object']
MRO: ['C', 'D', 'ABC', 'object']
MRO: ['D', 'ABC', 'object']

This minimal-ish code block reproduces the issue:
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class D(ABC,):
    def __init__(
        self,
        _D__arg=None,
        *args,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        self.arg = _D__arg
        super(D, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs,)

    @abstractmethod
    def d_abstract_base_class(self):
        pass


class C(D, ABC,):
    def __init__(
        self,
        _C__arg=None,
        *args,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        self.arg = _C__arg
        super(C, self).__init__(
            _D__arg=self.arg,
            *args,
            **kwargs,
        )

    def d_abstract_base_class(self):
        return True
    @abstractmethod
    def c_abstract_base_class(self):
        pass


class B(D, ABC,):
    def __init__(
        self,
        _B__arg=None,
        *args,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        self.arg = _B__arg
        super(B, self).__init__(
            _D__arg=self.arg,
            *args,
            **kwargs,
        )

    def d_abstract_base_class(self):
        return True
    @abstractmethod
    def b_abstract_base_class(self):
        pass


class A(B,C,):  
    def __init__(
        self,
        _A__arg=None,
        *args,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        self.arg = _A__arg
        super(A, self).__init__(
            _B__arg=self.arg,
            _C__arg=self.arg,
            *args,
            **kwargs,
        )

    def b_abstract_base_class(self):
        return True
    def c_abstract_base_class(self):
        return True


a = A(a=1,)

Similar questions referencing this error in SO do not appear to be addressing multiple inheritance as a root cause.
The code block above, doesn't appear to have any of the common issues addressed in these related questions including: missing "self" argument in method definitions, positional / keyword argument collisions, out of order positional args, etc.
edit:
InSync suggested this earlier question:
What does 'super' do in Python?
which has a lot of great info, some excellent explanations, and was definitely worth the read! However, it doesn't appear to address this specific question since my code is already using super.  I did try switching to the Python3 approach to calling super:
super().__init__() which eliminated the error, but didn't pass args to the parent classes--which is kind of the reason I'm trying to do this.
Am I misunderstanding multiple inheritance in Python? Or some more general Pythonic concept?
If it helps:

Python 3.11.6
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS


The many underscores and unconventional spaces (or lack of spaces) and commas make this unnecessarily hard to read, can you simplify the names and formatting (maybe use an automated code formatter like black)?

hey @mkrieger1 np, i'll edit and simplify

B.__init__() calls C.__init__() with _D__arg_0 = 1, which is also what C.__init__() does with D.__init__(). If the MROs are all as expected, what is this question about?

Does this answer your question? What does 'super' do in Python? - difference between super().__init__() and explicit superclass __init__()

If it's relevant, Pylint is giving me "Keyword argument before variable positional arguments list in the definition of __init__ function (W1113:keyword-arg-before-vararg)"

Beside the point, but Pylint is also giving me "Redefining name 'a' from outer scope (W0621:redefined-outer-name)" at a=2 in A.__init__. You could rename A(a=1) as like, a_instance or something like that. a_instance = A(a=1)

@wjandrea  good point.  i'm updating code to clarify in response to various comments

@InSync in response to your earlier comment, the MROs are as expected, which would lead me to believe that the resolution of attributes in this multiple inheritance situation would be handled.  However, (and this is what the question is about) Python generates a "Typedef: got multiple values for keyword argument" error.

The wrong part in this code is just what the error message reads:
You can pass an argument either as positional, or as named - but not as both.
And you are making your calls inserting explicit nam  arguments to the c, b and d parameters placing any position-defined arguments.
Actually, since you have non-matching initial parameters to your subclasses, the ideal thing for you would be not to use positional arguments at all, and just require any arguments, to any subclass, to be named: that would avoid a lot of headache. Still, there can be space for anonymous positional parameters there, as long as you pass them in the correct order. (pass the first argument, be it c, d or whatever as positional only, then *args).
Also, note that classes B and C can't "know" they are calling "D" in super() (one of them won't be when instantiating a) and you are passing explicit conflicting values to the d argument.
That said, let me rewrite something similiar to your example (without the superfluous abstract methods, since they add nothing to the question), in a way that would work.
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class D(ABC,):
    def __init__(self, d=None, *args, **kwargs):
        # By declaring the first argument as either named or positional with 
        # a default, any call here _EITHER_ has `d` as a named argument
        # _OR_ has any positional parameters. One can't have both. 
        # we are better not allowing any positional only arguments (doing
        # that for the following classes):
        
        self.d = d
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs,)
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Instance of {self.__class__.__name__} with attrs: {self.__dict__}"


class C(D):
    def __init__(self, c=None, *, **kwargs):
        self.c = c
        # Note that the immediate super() class is determined at
        # runtime. If there is another "d" value incomming from a super() call
        # from "B.__init__" you will get an error message.
        
        # so you can't do:
        #super().__init__(d=self.c, **kwargs,)
        # But this is possible and will override any other value for "d"
        kwargs["d"] = self.c
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class B(D):
    def __init__(self, b=None, *, **kwargs):
        self.b = b 
        kwargs["d"] = self.b  # (may be overriden if C is in the MRO)
        super().__init__(**kwargs,)

class A(B,C):
    def __init__(self, a=2, *, **kwargs):
        self.a = a 
        kwargs["c"] = kwargs["b"] = self.a
        # alternatively, just add c and b values if they are not given:
        # if "c" not in kwargs: kwargs["c"] = self.a 
        # ...
        super(A, self).__init__(**kwargs,)


a = A(a=1,)


thanks for the response jsbueno, a couple of things.
all args should be keyword. code shouldn't be passing anything positionaly.

nice. The example already removes any positional keyword arguments , but for the definition of D. Also, if you want to allow "b, c, d" parameters to be passed explicitly when instatiating A, you have to use the pattern commented out for the c argument in A.__init__, in all classes. (if that is a lot of code, it is always possible to shorten it)

the actual--non-simplified--code does have matching argument names in child, parent, grandparent, etc classes.  the initial version of the code included in this question used the approach i took to address this in the "read" code: using something like "_A__a" as the argument name for class A's keyword arg.  the code was simplified to try to improve readability.  looks like i oversimplified :)  going to fix.

looking through your solution more carefully, it looks like this could solve my problem.  i was initially hesitant to explicitly push to kwargs, but it seems this is what i should have been doing from the beginning.  ty!
